# Change font of a part of a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts, jlabel

I want to change **only** the first two words of a JLabel to a different font than the rest of the JLabel. I have found that I could make a JPanel, and have two JLabels with different fonts in it. I cannot use this way, because I can only have one JLabel (This is since I have a mouse listener which changes the text of that JLabel based on entrance or exit of different other JLabels, which are in a seperate JPanel). Is there any way? I have tried this (adding a JLabel side by side to another JLabel):

```
JLabel Giraffesays = new JLabel("Giraffe says:");
        Giraffesays.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 60)); 
        status.setText(Giraffesays +"Hi!"); //status is a JLabel
```

but this didn't work. I also tried making it a string:

```
String Giraffesays = "Giraffe says:
        Giraffesays.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 60)); 
        status.setText(Giraffesays +"Hi!"); //status is a JLabel
```

But you cannot change the font of a String...

Comment: I would use two JLabels added side by side for the easiest solution. You state: `" I cannot use this way, because I can only have one JLabel (This is since I have a mouse listener which changes the text of that JLabel based on entrance or exit of different other JLabels, which are in a seperate JPanel)"` -- this seems like a false reason. Can you explain more about why this prevents you from doing this?

Comment: If you need multiple text formatting, possibly you can go for `html string` for JLabel, or `JTextPane`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I would have to change both strings of each JFrame in the main panel in each mouse listener, and I have many. Also, since my JLabel used countless times throughout the code, changing it would also mean altering my entire code. Rather than doing that, I want to be able to just set the text with different fonts within it. Thanks

Comment: A simple couple of setter methods would solve this easily. Unless you wish to change the type of display to a JTextPane or use HTML as @Arvind wisely suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `HTML String` with `JLabel`:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      @Override public void run() {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Text formatting");
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        String giraffesays = "<html><span style=\"font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;\">Giraffe says :</span>Hi there!</html>";
        frm.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(giraffesays));
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frm.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

> This is the line with the error

```
String giraffesays = "<html><font size="6"><span style=\"font-family:Arial;\">Giraffe says :</font></span></html>";
```

Problem is you need to escape the quotes `size=\"6\"`.

Comment: **After trying to do it the HTML way, I tried this: ->**                                                   String giraffesays = "<html><font size="6"><span style=\"font-family:Arial;\">Giraffe says :</font></span></html>" ; **I got the error on my font size = 6, and I dont know why. I am very new to using HTML with java, so I was wondering if you can help me?:** -> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable -> **I understand this, but shouldn't it work even if the left isn't a variable since I declared it <html>? Thanks**

Comment: String giraffesays = "<html><font size="6"><span style=\"font-family:Arial;\">Giraffe says :</font></span></html>"; **NEXT LINE**
   status.setText(giraffesays +"Hi there!");

Comment: @Rich, text `Hi there!` needs to wrapped around by `<html></html>`, also use style attribute instead of using `font` tag.

Comment: Why would I need to do that? The text "Hi there!" has nothing to do with the other html text..? Also, after doing that the same error exists. It is a problem with my font size I think...?

Comment: **This is the line with the error** String giraffesays = "<html><font size="6"><span style=\"font-family:Arial;\">Giraffe says :</font></span></html>";

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have liked and marked best answer!

Comment: In addition, you can also use the HTML `<b>` and `<i>` elements instead of having to use the (rather cumbersome) `<font>` element.

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches would be:

1. use two separate `JLabels`
2. `JComponent` supports HTML, so you could simply use font tags to change the appeareance of the text. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

Comment: **After trying to do it the HTML way, I tried this: ->**                                                   String giraffesays = "<html><font size="6"><span style=\"font-family:Arial;\">Giraffe says :</font></span></html>" ; **I got the error on my font size = 6, and I dont know why. I am very new to using HTML with java, so I was wondering if you can help me?:** -> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable -> **I understand this, but shouldn't it work even if the left isn't a variable since I declared it <html>? Thanks** I will post the full code in the next line!

Comment: String giraffesays = "<html><font size="6"><span style=\"font-family:Arial;\">Giraffe says :</font></span></html>"; **NEXT LINE** status.setText(giraffesays +"Hi there!");

Comment: @Rich the reason isn't a problem with HTML. Atleast not if this is the precise copy paste of your code. This part: `<font size="6">` should be `<font size=\"6\">` otherwise the 6 won't be interpreted as a part of the string

Comment: Although you weren't marked best answer, I have thanked you by lliking your answer. Thanks so much!